# How can I make parts of my mesh slightly transparent in sculpt/edit mode?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, sculpting

Im sculpting a character model, and there are bits of it that get in the way.
I could hide them completely, but then its easy to lose track of proportions and move things where they shouldn't be.

Is there any way to make an object or part of a mesh transparent while editing it?

Comment: Give them a material with transparency and use a material preview.  This doesn't work with dynotopo sculpting, but nothing will, because dynotopo sculpting does not preserve any kind of face or vertex data.

Comment: ok first this wont work with dyntopo very well . but you can use **Vertex Weight Proximity**  and **Mask** modifiers to hide some parts of your mesh with like an empty or something. with dyntopo you can add details you need and then assign vertex data to group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended finding out the answer on my own.
I can add a material to the section I want to make transparent and in the material options, under Viewport Display, you can select a color with an Alpha value, so you can keep working in solid mode